# Add mysql connector support to jaspersoft studio

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse

I want to use a mysql connection in jaspsersoft studio. The mysql connector is not included, and needs to be added, as is described in various places, e.g. [here](http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/800539/jaspersoft-studio-data-connector-mysql). Unfortunatly, it seems to be common knowledge how to do this - no one describes how. I have been trying all sorts of locations for the mysql-connector-java-5.1.30-bin.jar file with no success. Can someone tell me the exact steps on how to add the mysql connector?
I have jaspersoft studi 5.5.1, mysql-connector-java-5.1.30 on ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: From your provided link: "FYI the DataAdapter Wizard has a tab where the path to the driver jar file is entered".  Are you adding it to the classpath?  What exact steps are you trying?

Comment: Thank you for poiting me to that link again, I used the wizard tab to add the jar ... that was easy. If you repost your comment as an answer, I will be happy to accept it.

Comment: Done deal. Glad it worked. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regardless of where you decide you want to put the actual library files, you need to ensure it's added to Jaspersoft Studio's classpath.

From your provided link: "FYI the DataAdapter Wizard has a tab where the path to the driver jar file is entered".

Comment: For those like myself wondering how to do this, there's a tab labeled 'Driver Classpath' in the data adapter wizard. Just click that and then click 'Add'.